# WPF How to make "layer"

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a small appplication which is single windowed...
I have formated everything with care .. The window contains a grid which has 2 columns.. The second is auto and the first  is of type *.(takes the remaining space)

Is there a way to change the content of the first column ?(to display a chart for example)
The only solution i can think is a tabcontrol with invisible tabs to switch programmatically, or create a custom user control and place it somehow..but the last solution i think sucks because the content i want to display isnt just a user control..
In java i could do this very easilly,is there any solution here?(i dont want to mess the design view!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

- put a `<ContentControl>` in XAML where you want to exchange contents.
- give it a name (x:Name)
- Now you can target the control. It supports `IAddChild` such that you can attach any child object to be displayed.

Comment: well, what kind of help do you want? if you separate the possible contents into its own content controls, you can use the designer over there...